# C# is it possible to escalate "possible null reference" warning to caller of method

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have a class which structurally isn't very different from this:

```cs
internal class Class1
{
    string? member;

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(member))]
    private void SetupMembers() => member = "some value";

    private int DoCalculation() => member.Length; // Possible null reference

    public int ExternalMethod()
    {
        SetupMembers();
        return DoCalculation();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to escalate the "possible null reference" check to the method calling `DoCalculation` rather than having it done in `DoCalculation`? Something along the line of a `DissallowNullForMember` attribute?

There seems to exist something which does what I want if I just have it as arguments rather than referring members. (the `DisallowNull` attribute).

It's not very hard to just ignore the warning either. (Could just use a !)

But I want to preserve the warning for when it is needed, like if I hadn't called `SetupMembers` in `ExternalMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. Nullable reference types are really syntactic sugar

You could use some custom class with generics & implicit operators

```cs
public class NeverNull<T>
{
    private NeverNull(T value)
    {
        Value = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public static implicit operator T(NeverNull<T> neverNull) => neverNull?.Value ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Never pass a null value");

    public static implicit operator NeverNull<T>(T value) => new NeverNull<T>(value);
}
```

All this really does though is abstract your null checking, and an implicit operator should never throw.